# How can I record everything typed/deleted/modified in my form?

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to replay all the actions done by the user in my form on an individual admin page dedicated to review the form's submissions. I want to replay my user's actions like a video, I want to see everything he deleted and modified in chronological order. Is there any similar solution out? If not, how can I do this? Do I need to store every character and their timestamps in database using PHP, and then somehow replay them?

Answer (score 0):

you can record theese actions with jQuery by storing time of action and key pressed while some inputs are focused, then if you want to store info, then pass it somehow (ajax for example) to sql database. Else if you want to replay before leaving page, there is no need to storing info.
Anyway, this is bit useless, you should consider not doing this at all